# How to define typescript interfaces with predefined string literals that restricts allowed types for common attributes?

Tags: typescript

Idea is that there are two different interfaces called A and B, that has a validation and variant prop, and I am trying to write a function that takes only variant and validation values (field is already defined) to create an Example object.
I keep getting error at below highlighted code line, can someone kindly help to explain what's going on here? Why ts complains? And any ts documentation that explain this behaviour?

```
export interface A {
    field: "Af";
    variant: "A";
    validation: boolean;
}

export interface B {
    field: "Af";
    variant: "B";
    validation: number;
}

export type C = A | B;

const c: C = {
    field: "Af",
    variant: "A",
    validation: false,
};

class Example {
    private data: C;
    constructor(data: C) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

const test = (type: Omit<C, "field">): Example => {
    const d: C = { // should not throw error (Why throwing error here)
        field: "Af",
        ...type,
    };
    const example = new Example(d);
    return example;
};

test({ variant: "A", validation: true }); // should not throw error
test({ variant: "B", validation: 1 }); // should not throw error
test({ variant: "A", validation: 2 }); // should throw error
test({ variant: "B", validation: true }); // should throw error
```

Error I am getting is

```
Type '{ variant: "A" | "B"; validation: number | boolean; field: "Af"; }' is not assignable to type 'C'.
  Type '{ variant: "A" | "B"; validation: number | boolean; field: "Af"; }' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Types of property 'variant' are incompatible.
      Type '"A" | "B"' is not assignable to type '"B"'.
        Type '"A"' is not assignable to type '"B"'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `Omit` in the base libraries is not distributive. So the resulting type will be an object type that mangles the union (`{ variant: "A" | "B"; validation: number | boolean; field: "Af"; }`)

You ca easily write a distributive version of `Omit` though using distributive conditional types:

```
type DistributiveOmit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = 
    T extends T ? Omit<T, K> : never;

const test = (type: DistributiveOmit<C, "field">): Example => {
    const d: C = { // ok
        field: "Af",
        ...type,
    };
    //...
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#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-OF1wtZieMs+Lr+XoARjgdY4DbgTZbbY7XZ7mKg-cHwCKw6abnsbULvm6ATgACYF-XrSvm626MLuxBezvoHuDwWj2OJ2fp0rYVDlrO9G0fNsHi3PtPyAA)

Comment: Thank you this does solve the issue I am having, can I trouble you to modify this  so that it can be used to omit multiple props? Ex: `DistributiveOmit<C, "field | variant">`

Comment: `DistributiveOmit<C, "field" | "variant">` should work. Does't it ?

Comment: Sorry, it does not.

Comment: I accepted the answer cause it did answer the original question have posted, but it does not work with multiple props.  any idea why?

Comment: @v1shva I mean it depends what you are trying to do. It will omit the properties from `C`, but the resulting  union `{ validation: boolean;} | { validation: number; }` will not really be assigable to `C` even if you do add the variant back since it can;t validate between the two casses. https://tsplay.dev/WzDPkN

Comment: okay, got it, in that case if we assume A and B both has a prop `field2: "Af2"` how to omit both field and field2 ?

Comment: @v1shva `DistributiveOmit<C, "field" | "field2">` works https://tsplay.dev/N9Vnom